# How to check the size() or isEmpty() for ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, web-crawler, executorservice

I am trying to prototype a simple structure for a Web crawler in Java. Until now the prototype is just trying to do the below:

- Initialize a Queue with list of starting URLs
- Take out a URL from Queue and submit to a new Thread
- Do some work and then add that URL to a Set of already visited URLs

For the Queue of starting URLs, I am using a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` for synchronizing. 
To spawn new Threads I am using `ExecutorService`.

But while creating a new Thread, the application needs to check if the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is empty or not. I tried using:

- `.size()`
- `.isEmpty()`

But both seem not to be returning the true state of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

The problem is in below block:

```
while (!crawler.getUrl_horizon().isEmpty()) {
                workers.submitNewWorkerThread(crawler);
            }
```

And because of this, ExecutorService creates all the Threads in its limit, even if the input is only 2 URLs.

**Is there a problem with the way multi-threading is being implemented here? If not, what is the better way to check the state of ConcurrentLinkedQueue?**

Starting class for the application:

```
public class CrawlerApp {

    private static Crawler crawler;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        crawler = = new Crawler();
        initializeApp();
        startCrawling();

    }

    private static void startCrawling() {
        crawler.setUrl_visited(new HashSet<URL>());
        WorkerManager workers = WorkerManager.getInstance();
        while (!crawler.getUrl_horizon().isEmpty()) {
            workers.submitNewWorkerThread(crawler);
        }
        try {
            workers.getExecutor().shutdown();
            workers.getExecutor().awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void initializeApp() {

        Properties config = new Properties();
        try {
            config.load(CrawlerApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("url-horizon.properties"));
            String[] horizon = config.getProperty("urls").split(",");
            ConcurrentLinkedQueue<URL> url_horizon = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
            for (String link : horizon) {
                URL url = new URL();
                url.setURL(link);
                url_horizon.add(url);
            }
            crawler.setUrl_horizon(url_horizon);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

`Crawler.java` which maintains the Queue of URLs and Set of already visited URLs.

```
public class Crawler implements Runnable {
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<URL> url_horizon;

    public void setUrl_horizon(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<URL> url_horizon) {
        this.url_horizon = url_horizon;
    }

    public ConcurrentLinkedQueue<URL> getUrl_horizon() {
        return url_horizon;
    }

    private Set<URL> url_visited;

    public void setUrl_visited(Set<URL> url_visited) {
        this.url_visited = url_visited;
    }

    public Set<URL> getUrl_visited() {
        return Collections.synchronizedSet(url_visited);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        URL url = nextURLFromHorizon();
        scrap(url);
        addURLToVisited(url);

    }

    private URL nextURLFromHorizon() {
        if (!getUrl_horizon().isEmpty()) {
            URL url = url_horizon.poll();
            if (getUrl_visited().contains(url)) {
                return nextURLFromHorizon();
            }
            System.out.println("Horizon URL:" + url.getURL());
            return url;

        }
        return null;

    }

    private void scrap(URL url) {
        new Scrapper().scrap(url);
    }

    private void addURLToVisited(URL url) {
        System.out.println("Adding to visited set:" + url.getURL());
        getUrl_visited().add(url);
    }

}
```

`URL.java` is just a class with `private String url` and overriden `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Also, `Scrapper.scrap()` just has dummy implementation until now:

```
public void scrap(URL url){
        System.out.println("Done scrapping:"+url.getURL());
    }
```

`WorkerManager` to create Threads:

```
public class WorkerManager {
    private static final Integer WORKER_LIMIT = 10;
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(WORKER_LIMIT);

    public ExecutorService getExecutor() {
        return executor;
    }

    private static volatile WorkerManager instance = null;

    private WorkerManager() {
    }

    public static WorkerManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (WorkerManager.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new WorkerManager();
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public Future submitNewWorkerThread(Runnable run) {
        return executor.submit(run);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The reason why you end up creating more Threads than there are URLs in the queue is because it is possible (and in fact likely) that none of the Threads of the Executor start until you go through the `while` loop a lot of times.

Whenever working with threads you should always keep in mind that the threads are scheduled independently and run at their own pace except when you explicitly synchronize them. In this case, the threads can start at any time after the `submit()` call, even though it seems you'd like each one to start and go past `nextURLFromHorizon` before a next iteration in your `while` loop.

### Solution

Consider dequeuing the URL from the queue before submitting the `Runnable` to the Executor. I also suggest defining a `CrawlerTask` that is submitted to the Executor once, rather than a `Crawler` that is submitted repeatedly. In such design you wouldn't even need a thread-safe container for the URLs to-be-scraped.

```
class CrawlerTask extends Runnable {
   URL url;

   CrawlerTask(URL url) { this.url = url; }

   @Override
   public void run() {
     scrape(url);
     // add url to visited?
   }
}

class Crawler {
  ExecutorService executor;
  Queue urlHorizon;

  //...

  private static void startCrawling() {
    while (!urlHorizon.isEmpty()) {
      executor.submit(new CrawlerTask(urlHorizon.poll());
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Your design makes more sense obviously. But in case I need to synchronize threads explicitly, should I do a class level `synchronized` method or create a `Object lock` and use `synchronized` block?

Comment: Also, even if I create a `CrawlerTask` I still need to pass a reference to `Crawler` object which has the set of already visited URLs.

Comment: `synchronized` cannot alone ensure that threads execute in the order you want. It just prevents two threads from entering the body of the block/method at the same time. If you want a thread to wait until another one does something, you will need to use `Object.wait` and `Object.notify`. Using concurrent `Queue` in a producer-consumer pattern uses these mechanisms internally, but then one thread `.add()`s and another one `.remove()`s from the queue.

Comment: To answer your second question, yes, you can pass `Crawler` or just make `CrawlerTask` an inner (non-static) class of `Crawler` so that it can access the `Crawler`s scope. Then use a thread-safe set for previously-visited URLs.